# How could I force foreman to run the rbenv rather than system default ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreman

I'm going to run rake tasks with an ruby script.

But I think foreman has no way to specify the ENVIRONMENT before running pure ruby script (I want to run with rbenv 2.2.2 )

I'm sure `eval "$(rbenv init -)" ; cd /home/user123/workspace/lazy-bird-website/ ; ruby notification_periodic_tasks.rb` works in the crontab, but how to do the identical command with foreman

## Procfile

```
worker: ruby notification_periodic_tasks.rb
```

I got this exception

## exception

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- pry (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from notification_periodic_tasks.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

## ruby script

```
require 'pry'
require 'active_support/all'
require 'rufus-scheduler'
require 'awesome_print'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.every '30m' do
  ap("start tasks")
  system("RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake notification:add")
  system("RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake notification:send")
end

scheduler.join
```

## .zshrc

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

## vipw

```
user123:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/user123:/bin/zsh
```

Comment: Could you put a `.ruby-version` file in the directory where the script lives?

Comment: I've already put it `2.2.2` in `.ruby-version `  it didn't work, but the problem is due to bash or zsh ?

Comment: Have you verified that rbenv is working properly?  What does `rbenv version` print in this directory?

Comment: @SunilD. How could I check that, because when I login, then type `zsh`, and then i can run the script correctly.

Comment: If it works when you go into zsh it means that you/someone setup rbenv in that shell and not the bash shell. It's simple enough to install it either shell, the instructions are on the rbenv website. There are many ways to verify rbenv is working properly, one of them is to type the command `rbenv version`.

Comment: I can simply verify it on the console (and it works), but it's hard for me to debug the foreman script.

Comment: I'm sure `eval "$(rbenv init -)" ; cd /home/user123/workspace/lazy-bird-website/ ; ruby notification_periodic_tasks.rb` works in the crontab, but how to do the identical command with foreman